# Android studio - Google Map : Check if person is in the circle

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geometry

I'm developping an application with Android Studio in Java. I have a problem. I work with Google Map. I have created a circle but I don't know how I can detect if the location of the person is in the circle.
I have found something to check that but it doesn't work, my application crash instantly.
Thank's for your help.

The code that I found :

```
        float[] distance = new float[2];

        Location.distanceBetween(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longitude,distance);
        if ( distance[0] <= circle.getRadius())
        {
            // Inside The Circle
        }
        else
        {
            // Outside The Circle
        }
```

And this is all my code (without the imports lines) :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private  TextView mTextViewResult;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker markertest;
    double lat;
    double longi;
    boolean zoom;

    float[] distance = new float[2];
    Circle circle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        zoom = true;
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        //openActivite();
        fetchLastLocation();
        Check();
        runnabletest.run();
    }

    public void Check(){
        currentLocation.distanceBetween(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longitude,distance);
        if ( distance[0] <= circle.getRadius())
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            // Outside The Circle
        }
    }

    private Runnable runnabletest = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fetchLastLocation();
            mHandler.postDelayed(runnabletest, 10000);
        }
    };


    private void fetchLastLocation(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude()
                    +""+currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
                    lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                    longi = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, longi);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Vous");
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(48.8534, 2.3488);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions2 = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng2).title("Point d'arrivée").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions2);
        circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng2).radius(500.0).strokeWidth(3f).strokeColor(Color.BLUE).fillColor(Color.argb(70, 150, 50, 50)));
        if(zoom == true){
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng2));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng2, 5));
        }
        zoom = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation){

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    fetchLastLocation();;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

And the errors in the logs :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.okiep, PID: 21205
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.okiep/com.example.okiep.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.okiep.MainActivity.Check(MainActivity.java:81)
        at com.example.okiep.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: When the application crashes, are there any error messages? Please post any logs that you have so that we can help you better.

Comment: I have answered you just under.
Thank's :)

Comment: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you have a NullPointerException where the null value is `currentLocation`. This means at the point where it is called on line 81 in the `Check` method, it has a null value. Looking at the sequence of execution, it seems like the right place to put your call to the `Check` method should be inside the `onSuccess` callback within `fetchLastLocation`.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        zoom = true;
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        //openActivite();
        runnabletest.run();
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude()
                    +""+currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
                    lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                    longi = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                    Check(); // Call the Check method here
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, longi);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Vous");
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(48.8534, 2.3488);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions2 = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng2).title("Point d'arrivée").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions2);
        circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng2).radius(500.0).strokeWidth(3f).strokeColor(Color.BLUE).fillColor(Color.argb(70, 150, 50, 50)));
        if(zoom == true){
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng2));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng2, 5));
        }
        zoom = false;
        fetchLastLocation(); //move fetchLastLocation to here
    }
```

Also, by java convention, method names should be camelcase. Your `Check` method should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I will try and I will tell you.

Comment: I put the code inside the onSuccess but it crash instanly. What do you think ? Thank's :)

Comment: Going to need more information. What is the error message? Please update your question with any logs you have.

Comment: @Snweyzer That error means that `circle` is null at the point where it is called in `Check`. Shift `fetchLastLocation` into `onMapReady`. I have edited my answer to reflect this. Please update the question with the error message you had in your last comment.

Comment: Thank's bro I succeed thank to your help ! <3
I close this post, thank's again !